# Generalization of Bezout's Theorem. Steiner's mistake?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

Let $V_i\subseteq \mathbb{P}^d$ be an irreducible algebraic variety of dimension $d_i$ and degree $n_i$. Bezout's theorem says that if $d_1+d_2=d$ then $$V_1\cap V_2$$ has
$$n_1n_2$$ many points (counting multiplicity.)

${\bf Question\  1:}$ Is it true that if $d_1+d_2+d_3=d$ then 
     $$V_1\cap V_2 \cap V_3$$ has
$$n_1n_2n_3$$ many points (counting multiplicity.) ? 
Have found an old book that affirms this.
Here is an example that refutes it.

${\bf Example:}$ Let the points of $\mathbb{P}^5$ be identified as the coefficients of a projective conic in the plane.
Let $P$ be a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^5$ consisting of those conics passing through a given point. 
The statement that a conic is determined by $5$ points I write as $$P^5=1$$
meaning that if I intersect five of these hyperplanes, defined by distinct points of course, but still all denoted by $P$, I get a single point. The intersection of $5$ hyperplanes in $5$ space being a point (in  general).

Now let $L$ be the surface of conics tangent to a given line. 
It is known 
$$P^4L=2$$ meaning that there are two conics through $4$ given points and tangent to a given line. 
One sees that this implies that $L$ is a quadratic hypersurface. 
It follows from Bezout that 
$$P^3L^2=4$$ and this is ${\it correct}$. 
It then follows by duality that 
$$P^2L^3=4$$
$$PL^4=2$$
$$L^5=1$$ and these values are ${\it correct}$.

Jacob Steiner however at one point made the mistake that 
  $$P^2L^3=2^3$$
$$PL^4=2^4$$
$$L^5=2^5$$

But doesnt this follow from the generalized Bezout theorem ?

${\bf Question 2:}$ What is the error is Steiner's supposition ?

Comment: Fulton _Intersection_ _Theory_ example 9.1.8: the Veronese of double lines (tangent to any conic) account for 31 of the 32 (excess intersection).

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thanks for that, so $L^5$ is actually infinite ?

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland If I understand correctly the Veronese surface  $V\subseteq L$ for all $L$. And since it is $2$ dimensional one must intersect it with at least, a $P^3$ to get a finite set. So all of the Steiner erroneous values are actually infinite.

Comment: But there is a way to calculate the equivalency in the example above: $\int_{\rm Veronese} (1+4h)^5\cdot (1-9h+51h^2))=31$, where $h$ is the class of a line in the Veronese$\simeq {\Bbb P}^2.$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Yes, I have a copy of the book, systematic study of it is a pleasure that awaits me in the future.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland So $L^3$ which is $2$ dimensional, must actually be reducible, one component being the Veronese surface. The intersection of $P^2$ with each of those components is $4$, points. Which explains why the correct value of $4$ and not $8$.

Comment: The wikipedia article is also fairly detailed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner%27s_conic_problem

Comment: @TabesBridges Good to know, didnt realize this calculation was such common knowledge, it took me long enough to understand it....

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I mean, "common knowledge" might be a bit of a stretch, but the recent book of Eisenbud and Harris on intersection theory IS called *3264 and All That*...

Comment: @TabesBridges  Do you know how many cubic space curves are tangent to $12$ quadric surfaces ? 5819539783680. Maybe thats the title of the sequel....